# Error while building cordova app

Tags: android, cordova, github

I have a GitHub repo: https://github.com/zyver-meeps/switcher.

This has my cordova files on it. When i try to compile it, cordova gives me this error:

`enzotech2@iLuvLinux:~/Documents/GitHub/Switcher$ cordova build android
Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory`

When I try to run it verbose, it gives me this: (https://pastebin.com/C5NkgGM8)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all you should install android sdk, then you should install target android platform sdk (if you want to run with android 6.0 you should install platform 23 from SDK Manager). Did you already install Android SDK ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to type below command

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/environment
```

after fire this command, gedit is open,
set your ANDROID_HOME path like,

ANDROID_HOME="/home/mtfa/android/Sdk/

save it and logged out
after logged in your path is set.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to execute command `cordova platform add android` before `build`

Follow this guide if problem not solved: [Cordova Guide](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/cli/index.html)